# Перегрузка оператора присваивания для элементов класса

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Имеется класс:

```
template<class T>
struct settings_element
{
    settings_element (const T &def_value, const char *def_name, const char *def_menu_name): name {def_name}, menu_name {def_menu_name}
    {
        value = def_value;
    }

    settings_element (const settings_element &) = delete;

    bool operator== (const T &another) const
    {
        return value == another;
    }

    bool operator!= (const T &another) const
    {
        return value != another;
    }

    operator T& ( )//ov1
    {
        return value;
    }

    T &operator= (settings_element &another)//ov2
    {
        value = another.value;
        return *this;
    }

    settings_element &operator= (T &another)//ov3
    {
        value = another;
        return *this;
    }


private:
    T value;

    const std::string name, menu_name;
};
```

Нужно чтобы это работало следующим образом:

```
settings_element<int> a {123, "name", "name2"}
int val = a;
int new_val = 1234;
a = new_val;
```

А работает только `int val = a;`
благодаря благодаря  перегрузке ov1

Answer (score 0):

Объявите этот оператор следующим образом

```
settings_element &operator= (const T &another)//ov3
                             ^^^^^
{
    value = another;
    return *this;
}
```

Иначе вы не сможете использовать этот оператор для присваивания вида

```
a = 10;
```

так как `rvalue 10` можно связывать лишь с константной `lvalue` ссылкой.

Также оператор преобразования типа лучше объявить следующим образом, используя квалификатор `const` для возвращаемого значения и для самого оператора:

```
operator const T& ( ) const 
{
    return value;
}
```

И в этот оператор копирующего присвоения следует добавить квалификатор `const` для параметра

```
T &operator= (const settings_element &another)//ov2
{
    value = another.value;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все у вас работает.
В том числе

```
int new_val = 1234;
a = new_val;
```

Не работает

```
a = 1234;
```

но это исправляется путем добавления `const`:

```
settings_element &operator= (const T &another)
```

А вот

```
settings_element (const T &def_value, 
                  const char *def_name,
                  const char *def_menu_name)
: name {def_name}, menu_name {def_menu_name}
```

вызывает у меня тоскливые предчувствия из-за проблем владения... Если вы передадите какую-то строку, которая изменится, или будет удалена, выйдя из области видимости etc etc - будут проблемы. Я бы эти строки копировал в объект класса.